# gdb evaluate function in process core

Tags: c, gdb

Is there a way to execute function in process core context in GDB?

The incentive is to run a function that will go through a large tree to find a specific node. I can walk the tree manually but I would like to build a function that will help me analyze the core.

Hence either a function or "GDB script" to run over the data tree.

Comment: Related question: (use pretty printer): [c++ - gdb pretty printing with direct function calls - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578320/gdb-pretty-printing-with-direct-function-calls)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to execute function in process core context in GDB?

No: you need a "live" inferior process for that.

> I can walk the tree manually but I would like to build a function that will help me analyze the core.

You can do that using [Python scripting](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html) built into recent GDB versions.

Answer (score 2):

gdb can call C functions. If you type `p myfunction(...parameters...)`, gdb will evaluate the expression and print the returned value. Of course, the program you're debugging must be stopped.

Comment: I understand that on a running program this will work (and thanks for the input). My problem is that the program has already crashed and I need to call a function from the core context no a running program.

Comment: Uhm... no, too late :( . The only hope is a gdb script, sorry

Comment: Of course, if you can catch the exception in gdb, the process is still alive and you can call your function.

Comment: No exception in my world **C** :)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I'd say "segmentation fault" :D