# How do I configure GDB correctly, to stop error "You can't do that without a process to debug"

Tags: gdb

Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1

I am trying to call a function in a compiled C program and get the following:

```
"(gdb) call getVarName(someParam)
 You can't do that without a process to debug."
```

There are no other codes or messages.

I can run the program from the shell prompt 
jef@ubuntu$ ./program.
I can run the program within gdb after designating the file. Permissions are 777 (just to cover all bases).

Based on research, I set the SHELL with "export SHELL=/bin/bash"
and
set kernal.yama.ptrace_scope = 0 in /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf

I still get the same behavior.

Comment: Are you debugging a core dump?

Comment: Can you show the command line you invoked gdb with, and all relevant gdb commands you ran prior to the `call` ?

Comment: Not a core dump. an executeable C program.

Comment: (gdb)file program
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400994
(gdb)

Comment: i can also step through with "step" and "next" after setting a break point and "run".  "call" is what is giving me fits.

Comment: The root cause here is that the **OP forgot to `run` the program first**. For core dump see [c - gdb evaluate function in process core - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892597/gdb-evaluate-function-in-process-core) instead. (no solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I still get the same behavior.

Naturally.

The error you are getting means: you can't do this, *unless* you are debugging a live process.

This will work:

```
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
... GDB is now stopped, *and* you have a live process.
... you *can* call getVarName(...) now
(gdb) call getVarName(...)

(gdb) continue  # causes the process to run to end and exit
[Inferior 1 (process 195969) exited normally]

(gdb)  # Now you no longer have a live process, so you *again* can't
       # call functions in it.
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks!!
It makes sense now that I am out of the weeds and tunnel vision. I thought I could just call a function, but upon reflection what is the point of a break if that was possible...
Now I get why there are a lot of forum posts with this error around core files.

Comment: I have a question related to this one. I'm debugging `core dump` with gdb and tried to do `print errno` to get the error code. I got `You can't do that without a process to debug`. Can you suggest some idea about why isn't it possible to print `errno`?

Comment: @St.Antario That's a completely separate question. Please ask one, it doesn't cost you anything.